# Implementing Frequent Words Pseudocode

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement the frequent words pseudocode. According to a sample dataset I should be returning 2 frequent words but I'm only returning the first. 
Here is the pseudocode:

```
FrequentWords(Text, k)
    FrequentPatterns <-- an emty set
    for i <-- 0 to |Text| - k
        Pattern <-- the k-mer Text(i,k)
        Count(i) <-- PatternCount(Text,Pattern)
    maxCount <-- max value in array Count
    for i <-- 0 to |Text| - k
        if Count(i) = maxCount
        add Text(i,k) to FrequentPatterns
    remove duplicates from FrequentPatterns
    return FrequentPatterns
```

And here is my implementation:

```
def PatternCount(Text, Pattern):
    Count = 0
    for i in range(0, (len(Text) - len(Pattern) + 1)):
        if Text[i:i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
           Count = Count + 1
    return Count

def FrequentWords(Text, k):
    FrequentPatterns = [0]
    Count = [0] * (len(Text) - k + 1)
    for i in range(0, (len(Text) - k + 1)):
        Pattern = Text[i:i+k]
        Count[i] = PatternCount(Text, Pattern)
    maxCount = max(Count)    
    for i in range(0, (len(Text) - k + 1)):        
        if Count[i] == maxCount:
            FrequentPatterns = Text[i:i + k] 
            return FrequentPatterns
```

Here is the sample dataset:
ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT
4

I should get returned from code:
CATG GCAT

But I'm only getting the first - CATG. Please help.

Comment: What is a "frequent word"? Something of size 4 which can occur at an arbitrary index? How many times must the frequent word occur to be frequent?

Comment: Accumulate the words in a container and don't return till all of the dataset has been *searched*.

Comment: Can the patterns/words overlap?

Comment: The frequent words are size 4 and I want the one(s) that happen the most. They can also overlap.

Comment: So it looks like I'm returning my results too early as wwii says and should use a container to store the words to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT'
length = 4
```

I would use a dictionary to accumulate the results. Use a slice to extract the *next* word; add one to that word's value in the dictionary; then drop the first character in the string; loop while the string has a word in it.

```
result = {}
while len(s) >= length:
    word = s[:length]
    result[word] = result.get(word, 0) + 1
    s = s[1:]
```

You might be able to make use of [collections.Counter or collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) for that bit.  If the words cannot overlap, drop `length` characters from the front of the string. Keeping the process simple does result in a bit of inefficiency when the character(s) are removed from the string at the bottom of the loop.  Unless the data is very long or the process is performed a LOT of times it shouldn't matter.

Then just find the word(s) with the highest *frequency*

```
most = max(result.values())
frequent = []
for key, value in results:
    if value == most:
        frequent.append(key)

#frequent = [key for key, value in result.items() if value == most]
```

---

Borrowing from an [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) you can make an iterator that produces *words* of the required length

```
def n_wise(iterable, n=2):
    '''s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ... for n=2'''
    tees = itertools.tee(iterable, n)
    for i, thing in enumerate(tees, 1):
        for _ in range(i):
            next(thing, None)
    return zip(*tees)
```

The counting portion of the procedure would change to

```
words = n_wise(s, length)
result = {}
for word in words:
    result[word] = result.get(word, 0) + 1
```

The keys in `result` will be tuples, e.g. `('C', 'A', 'T', 'G')` but they can be reconstructed with `''.join(('C', 'A', 'T', 'G'))`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'll try implementing this. I did use collections.defaultdict to do the frequent words earlier, but I still wanted to do it by just using the pseudocode with no imports.

Answer (score 1):

you should consider using list comprehensions.

```
def pattern_count(text, pattern):
     matches = ([x for x in range(len(text) - len(pattern) + 1) if pattern in text[x:len(pattern) + x]])
     return len(matches)


def frequent_words(text, k):
    counts = [pattern_count(text, text[x:x + k]) for x in range(len(text) - k)]
    return set([text[x:x + k] for x in range(len(text) - k) if counts[x] == max(counts)])
```

**pattern_count** will parse a string for a pattern. We splice the text character array, so we can check if that portion contains the pattern. This allows us to include overlapping entries in our results. For instance,

*pattern_count(ABABA, ABA)* -> results in 2, instead of 1.

```
print(pattern_count("BABBASDCABCBABDDASDBBCASDBAB", "BAB"))
[0] 3
```

**frequent_words** takes the same text but instead of a pattern, we give it an int for how long the pattern should be. Once we get a list of the number of occurrences for each pattern that meets our character **k** requirement, we filter it by taking the entries which occur the most frequently.  Finally, to remove any duplicates, we convert the list into a hashset which inherently prevents duplicate entries, thus returning a collection with only unique values.

Test:

```
print(frequent_words("BABBASDCABCBABDDASDBBCASDBAB", 3))
[0] {'BAB', 'ASD'}
```

Hope that was of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict` instead:

```
def FrequentWords(Text, k):
    FrequentPatterns = {}
    for i in range(0, (len(Text) - k + 1)):
        Pattern = Text[i:i+k]
        if Pattern in FrequentPatterns:
            FrequentPatterns[Pattern] += 1
        else:
            FrequentPatterns.update({Pattern: 1})
    for x in sorted(FrequentPatterns.items(), key=lambda m: m[1], reverse=True):
        print(x)
```

Comment: This works nice on my sample dataset, but I need to return the max frequency because the next dataset could have thousands of words.